# Issues with canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(x,y,1,1).data in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, canvas, colors

Recently I have been programming and have run across inconsistencies between browsers with the `document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext("2d").getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;` command. I have an image and a section of this image is colored rgb(246,247,247) (I set the color in photoshop). I am calling the `getImageData` method to get the image data at a clicked point, look at the color and if the color is inside a range (which I have defined in an array) it will plot a point on the area. I run this in IE and it works just as expected, the color comes out at rgb(246,247,247). The problem comes in when I run the exact same code with the exact same image in Chrome or Firefox, the browser says the color is rgb(246,247,246) and rgb(246,247,246), respectively. Why is the browser saying the colors are different than they actually are? Is there another way to get the color of a pixel in a canvas reliably?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, web browsers all render colors differently. The best way to ensure colors are always the same is to use web safe colors, and export images as PNG-8 with no gamma channel.